# How to set sql parameters

Tags: c#, mysql, database, sql-injection, sqlparameter

I try that code for use sql parameters but didnt work and didnt return any error. How can I fix it?

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM "+mw.db_name+".ananmez_genel Where hasta_id='@hastaid'";

string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

using (MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, connect))
    {
        connect.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hastaid",hasta_id);
        MySqlDataReader mdr;
        mdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (mdr.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                arti = (i + 1).ToString();
                kontrol = mdr.GetString("c_" + arti);
                if (kontrol == "True")
                {
                    ananmezcheck.ananmez_gnlkontrol(i, check);
                }
            }
            yirmibir.Text = mdr.GetString("txt_1");
        }
        connect.Close();
    }
```

If i using just like that, it works:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM "+mw.db_name+".ananmez_genel Where hasta_id='"+hastaid+"'";
```

so there is no problem in the database.

Answer (score 8):

This part is the problem:

```
Where hasta_id='@hastaid'
```

That's not using a parameter - that's searching for rows where the value of `hasta_id` is exactly the string `@hastaid`, because you've put it in a string literal. You need to get rid of the quotes:

```
Where hasta_id=@hastaid
```

*Then* it's looking for rows where the value of `hasta_id` matches the value of the parameter `@hastaid`.

Comment: Indeed. The identification as "this is a string literal" is already done by the SQL Paramters. That is one big reason we use them - there is no type ambiguity. The quotes do make sense as a primitive (and easily breakable) protection against SQL Injections with Stroing Connaction but you are going beyond that.

Comment: I have another problem in that.  string sql = "SELECT * FROM @dbname.ananmez_genel Where hasta_id=@hastaid"; I try to set dbname like parameter but return "Fatal error encountered during command execution." error.

Comment: @kamilkunt: You can not give the DB or Tablenames as a paramter. SQL simply does not support that. For this part you have to use string conaction. Note that string connaction from within something like a switch/case block should be save. It is save, so long as the user did not enter it manually.

Comment: @kamilkunt: No, you can't use parameters for things like database, table or column names. They're for *values*.

Comment: What more can I do for security? @Christopher

Comment: @kamilkunt: That's outside the scope of this question. Comments on answers should really be for clarification of the answer provided to the question asked.

Comment: @kamilkunt: The correct rule is: "Never use string conaction with direct userinput to build a querry". I had a case where I had to switch on the table/contents of a IN clause, wich was beyond Paramters in that language. But this switch happened on a basic 2 letter key provided by the user. Wich was then filtered through a switch/case statement with default. So any value I was conacting there, I was generating myself. Those values I could conact without worry.